# MySQL: Define Non Key as Unique per Compound Key

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

For a Java application (Spring Boot, Spring Data, Spring Data JPA) I am modelling a slowly changing dimension type 2 database table.

I wonder how I can design the keys in an optimal way:

I have:

```
@Id
private String partId;
@Id
private Date validFrom;

private Date validTo;
```

validTo gets `9999-12-31` if the row is valid.

If it is necessary to create a new row, the old row gets terminated:     `validTo` is set to `now`

and for the new row, the `validFrom` is set to `now`.

How can I assure that only one row exists with `validTo` = `9999-12-31` and only one row with `validFrom` = `now`?

If I would design it this way:

```
@Id
private String partId;

private Date validFrom;

@Id
private Date validTo;
```

I could loose consistency because several terminated rows exist with the same validFrom date.

If I make both dates to parts of the key, I loose even more consistency control.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to have more than one `@IdClass(MyClassCompoundKey.class)`?

Comment: No. It's not possible

Comment: So you need one valid row per `partId`? So that one `partId` have one valid having `validFrom` in present or past (and perhaps `validTo` in future) and the rest have `validTo` in past?

Comment: yes (sorry for the late reply - I was christmassed)

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: JPA does not allow you to easily perform this kind of check. You should validate the state of your data in your code directly, and only send something for JPA to insert once you are certain that you are happy with that operation.

Long Answer: Generally speaking, there are very few opportunities to perform this kind of validation at the JPA layer.  JPA is, by design, a stupid representation of simple data models being persisted in a database.  It is assumed that by the time data has reached the JPA layer of your application, it has already passed business logic validation at the business logic layer.

Essentially, the Business logic we want to implement is what follows:

> For every `partId`, no more than one entry in the table is allowed to exist which
>   has a `validTo` property set to a future time

Now, it just so happens to be that your current implementation of your application is such that the only date that should ever appear in the future is `9999-12-31`, and thus I can see how you might have thought about utilizing a database's unique constraints in order to implement a jerry-rigged version of your business logic.  This is a poor idea for one simple reason: That isn't what database constraints are for.

Database constraints exist to help the database serve its function: quickly, efficiently, and accurately answering your queries. It isn't the databases job to filter out data inputs that break your business rules, it is only the databases job to filter out data inputs that will prevent the database from being able to function properly. If you attempt to insert a duplicate primary key, that isn't a no-go because it breaks your business logic, it is a no-go because it breaks the databases data model.  You can't insert a second primary key into a database table for the same reason you can't put two separate-yet-identical keys into a `HashMap`, it just doesn't functionally work like that.

> If a rule doesn't have to do with helping the database be faster and
>   more reliable (i.e. uptime), then it probably doesn't belong on the
>   database

That being said, many databases (MySql included) do indeed have tools for implementing business logic at the database layer.  This is because there are indeed developers who believe that it is a good place for it.  That is fine.  JPA, however, does not expose that functionality because JPA was designed to make data storage as "stupid" as possible.  If you wanted to implement a constraint like this outside of the confines of JPA, it could be done with database concepts like triggers. You are free to implement these kinds of validations as DB Triggers, but JPA will likely take no part in it.